# Multi-level "where" clause (similar to order by)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

Given the following Heroes table:

```
firstName   |  lastName   | idNumber  | driverLicenseNumber
            |             |           |     
  Captain   |  America    |    1      |       10
  Spider    |  Man        |    2      |       20
```

I want to be able to query as following :

- given ID_NUMBER, DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER (params)
- if there exist a idNumber=ID_NUMBER fetch those matches (and only them ).
- else . if there exist a driverLicenseNumber=DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER fetch those matches

query example :

(ID_NUMBER=1 , DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER=20)    => [Captain America]

(ID_NUMBER=4 , DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER=20)    => [Spider Man]

(ID_NUMBER=4 , DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER=40)    => []

**My attempt:**

Im fetching all rows matching one of the fields:

```
Select * from Heroes where idNumber=ID_NUMBER or driverLicenseNumber=DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER;
```

Than iterating through the results in my code ( nodeJS).

Can I do this using mysql only (preferably without many joins and queries  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID_NUMBER match, return that row.

(Or) if the driverLicenseNumber match, return the row if the ID_NUMBER does not exist at all.

```
select * from Heroes
where idNumber = ID_NUMBER 
  or (driverLicenseNumber = DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER
      and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Heroes where idNumber = ID_NUMBER))
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethng like this?

```
... WHERE idNumber = ID_NUMBER OR (idNumber != ID_NUMBER AND driverLicenseNumber = DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER)
```

It fetch all rows where ID_NUMBER is set, and all rows WHERE only driver licence number is set.

If you can fetch also the rows where both ID are valid, use simply `or`.

```
... WHERE idNumber = ID_NUMBER OR driverLicenseNumber = DRIVER_LICENSE_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select *
from heroes
where idnumber = :id_number
union all
select *
from heroes
where 
    driverlicensenumber = :driverlicensenumber
    and not exists (select 1 from heroes where idnumber = :id_number)
```

I would expect this solution to perform well, especially if you have the following indexes:

```
heroes(id_number)
heroes(driverlicensenumber)
```